# How to transform a matrix's local space position into another's local space

Tags: xna, matrix

When looking at an example to learn how to do per pixel collision, I came across this:

```
// Calculate a matrix which transforms from A's local space into
// world space and then into B's local space
Matrix transformAToB = transformA * Matrix.Invert(transformB);
```

I have a (very) basic understanding of matrices, so I'm not too sure how this works, how can you convert the local space of one matrix to another by multiplying by the others inverted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transformation matrix has two functions: It can move and rotate a vector. We need one vector that we transform a little. Let's call it *positionRelativeToA*. We can transform this vector to the global world coordinates as follows:

```
Vector positionAbsolute = positionRelativeToA * transformA;
```

Of course, we can do the same with B:

```
Vector positionAbsolute = positionRelativeToB * transformB;
```

If we want to transform from the local space of B to A, we are interested in positionRelativeToB, so we change the above equation system a little:

```
//positionRelativeToB * transformB = positionRelativeToA * transformA;
//multiply with Matrix.inverse(transformB) on both sides
positionRelativeToB = positionRelativeToA * transformA * Matrix.inverse(transformB);
```

If you have to use that operation very often it makes sense to pre-calculate the Matrix * Matrix operation:

```
Matrix transformAToB = transformA * Matrix.inverse(transformB);
// ...
Vector positionRelativeToB = positionRelativeToA * transformAToB;
```